# Too many redirects

Tags: redirect, page

Hi I've just created a new page on the homepage and when I click it, it says too many page redirects. Why?

I believe I filled out the ID path and request path correctly

Comment: Which is your Magento version?

Answer (score 0):

I cant yet add a comment, why dont you try posting a Screen shot of it?

Try this

Open the .htaccess file

find the line

```
#RewriteBase /magento/
```

Change it to

```
 RewriteBase /magento2/
```

Note-: Save the .htaccess file, Clean all the var/cache and browser cache. Applicable for magento 2 only!